# Improve Performance SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When I ran the SQL query below, the performance is really slow.

There are over 400,000 rows in the table and I have index the `CheckDate` field.

`CheckDate` type is `datetime`

```
SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS TotalUser
FROM table
       WHERE DATE(CheckDate) = CURDATE()
```

How to improve it?

Comment: it this the only query which is slow? what about other queries returning almost same amount of data? what is the current response time?

Comment: You have to run `DATE` function on each `CheckDate` column and after that you have to check which correspond to `CURDATE()`. That's 400 000 dates being worked on and then (without index) compared to a value. Not really effective use of `DATE` / `CURDATE` functions.

Comment: @Bhushan I have updated the query. It take about 3 seconds to get a result even only 1 record found.

Comment: @N.B. I should have a separate fields? Eg: CheckDate, CheckTime?

Comment: why are you doing DATE(checkdate)? checkdate is already a DATETIME field, then why do you need to pass that column values to a function?

Comment: @Bhushan `checkdate` is  DATETIME. If you use `DATE()` - it will convert into DATE only

Comment: You can stick to 1 field, but you need to change your query slightly. I'm assuming you want to find records that have been created during current day. So instead of converting `CheckDate` to `DATE`, why not modify the your query to be `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE CheckDate BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 23:59:59');`

Comment: @user791022 **NO**, do _not_ seperate your fields, it'll just cause you more headaches later.

Comment: @N.B. - That might work for mySQL, but not everywhere else - most RDBMSs give milli- or nano-second accuracy.  I'd reccommend doing an exclusive on the _next_ day.

Comment: @X-Zero - post is tagged MySQL, MySQL's `DATETIME` type goes up to the second precision, not nano or millisecond so I don't really get the point of the lecture, it's pretty clear which RDBMS is in question and  since you have more accurate solution - why not post it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a range comparison instead of direct equality.  In other words, rewrite your query as

```
SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS TotalUser
  FROM table
  WHERE CheckDate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

or perhaps

```
SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS TotalUser
  FROM table
  WHERE CheckDate >= CURDATE() AND 
        CheckDate <  ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

See if that helps.

EDIT:
Or the first query could be reworked as

```
SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS TotalUser
  FROM table
  WHERE CheckDate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND
                          ADDDATE(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL -1 SECOND)
```

but that starts to get rather ugly, and I'm not sure if negative numbers are allowed in INTERVAL specifiers.

Anyways, the point is that when you find yourself wanting to truncate a date to see if it matches some other date a better option is often to use a ranged comparison.  More generally, try to avoid the use of functions on column values in the WHERE clause if there's any way to avoid it.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thats work and fast! thanks. That will only check current date and NOT the next day?

Comment: +1 : By using this structure, you are not performing any operations on the value being filtered.  You are simply saying "all the value in this range".  This means that the optimiser can use an index and process only the relevant records *(Where as the OPs query may well be scanning every entry in the whole index)*.  No changes you your model, only a change to your query.  *[Use the `>=` and `<` version to avoid including records stamped at exactly midnight the next day...]*

Comment: user791022 - the above *should* only find values for the current day, but run some tests and verify that's what you're getting.  If it's not, tweak as necessary.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis - Read Dems comment again, as your first version _will_ collect data from days stamped at midnight the next day.

Comment: @X-Zero - agreed - that's why I added the second version - or the first version could be modified to use DATE_ADD and the appropriate interval specifier for '23 hours 59 minutes'. It's code - modify as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You're not working with a functional index.  Your `WHERE` clause employs a function `DATE()` which will not use the index.  Use your `CheckDate` column as a direct comparator.

That does not mean it will go faster, but would be my first start.

Comment: Are you saying I should have a separate fields? For example: CheckDate (`DATE`) and CheckTime (`TIME`)?

Comment: NO!  Don't use a function around your attribute.  Use direct attribute comarisons e.g `CheckDate = f1(f2(foo))`

Answer (score 1):

The index on the CheckDate field wont be used because of the DATE function.

Every time you use any function on a column, the indexes on that column wont be used.

This is a situation where you should consider creating an computed column on the table with the expression DATE(CheckDate) and then create the index on the computed column (yes it will persist it on the DB, but I'm sure the index will then be used.)

Comment: oh, by the way, I didn't consider if you actually need to call the DATE function on the field. The logic is valid to any function.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a computed column DateCheckDate as DATE(CheckDate) and make it PERSISTED:

ALTER TABLE dbo.table ADD DateCheckDate AS (DATE(CheckDate)) PERSISTED;

2) create an index on DateCheckDate

3) change your query to

SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS TotalUser
FROM table
       WHERE DATECheckDate = CURDATE()

More info at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15